# Can someone check my sql is valid [postgresql]

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm just wondering if I'm using the `CHECK` constraint properly. I want ensure the `winner` and `loser` row different from each other.

```
    CREATE TABLE players (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    player_name VARCHAR
    );

    CREATE TABLE matches (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    winner INT REFERENCES players(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    loser INT REFERENCES players(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CHECK (winner <> loser)
    );
```

And there's other tables (as `VIEW`) that uses them.

```
CREATE VIEW view_wins AS
select players.id AS view_wins_id, count(matches.id) AS wins
FROM players LEFT OUTER JOIN matches
    ON players.id = matches.winner
GROUP BY players.id;

CREATE VIEW view_played AS
SELECT players.id AS view_played_id, count(matches.id) AS played
FROM players LEFT OUTER JOIN matches
    ON players.id = matches.winner OR players.id = matches.loser
GROUP BY players.id;

CREATE VIEW standings AS
SELECT players.id, players.player_name, view_wins.wins AS total_wins, view_played.played AS matches_played
FROM players, view_wins, view_played
WHERE players.id = view_wins_id AND players.id = view_played_id
ORDER BY total_wins DESC;

CREATE VIEW next_round AS
SELECT players.id AS player1_id, players.player_name AS player1_name,
players.id AS player2_id, players.player_name AS player2_name
FROM standings
WHERE player1_id.wins = player2_id.wins;
```

Comment: Yes, the `check` is fine. NB: StackOverflow is not the place to ask for recommended sites, tools, libraries, ...etc. See point 4 in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @trincot oh I'm sorry. Do you know any website I could get my codes check? That would be really helpful for a beginner like myself.

Comment: For letting people review your (functioning) code, see [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). But make sure to check their Help Center first, so you will be sure to ask on-topic questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CHECK` constraint is fine if `winner` and `loser` cannot assume the NULL value, but in that case you should have declared the columns as `NOT NULL`.

If these columns can be NULL, it might be better to write

```
CHECK (winner <> loser OR winner IS NULL OR loser IS NULL)
```